# Mistake while displaying GWT comboBox

Tags: gwt, combobox

In GWT combo box, I want to display part of the items but not all items as red color, so I add some label to the content, as follow:

```
**<span style='color:#FF0000;'>ABC - ABC</span>**
```

Well, it's ok when it's in dropdownlist.
But after I selected the item with label, both the content and label appear in combo box, just like this: **`<span style='color:#FF0000;'>ABC - ABC</span>`** but not like this which I want: **ABC - ABC**,the label doesn't work.

I've tried to filter the label in method onSelect() with regex, but if I use comboBox.setValue(), the value I get will be changed. For example:

comBox.setDisplayField("Name");
comBox.setValueField("id");

If I use comboBox.setValue(str.replaceAll(regex, "")) in the method onSelect(), the value will be the '**Name**' but not the '**id**'.

Have I made me understood? Is there anyone who has encountered this question ever or someone know the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use https://code.google.com/p/advanced-suggest-select-box/

It's exactly designed for these advanced cases: You have a renderer for each 'space': one for the list and one for the selected item(s). You can also replace the component responsible for displaying the text to adapt it to your needs

The demo is not for the latest jar but for the content of the svn version which is pretty stable
http://1vu-widgets.appspot.com/IntoGwt.html

Comment: Thx for your enthusiastic help. Finally, I solved the question by using the method -- public void setTitle(java.lang.String title)(http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/form/ComboBox.html#setTitle(java.lang.String))
Set a color value into combo box's store and then 
Template tpl = new Template("<div class=\"x-combo-list-item\" style=\"color:{color};\" id={Id}>{Name}</div>");
     localCB.setTpl(tpl);